# Proving $3(\sin x -\cos x)^4 +4(\sin^6 x +\cos^6x) +6(\sin x +\cos x)^2 =13$

Tags: trigonometry

> Prove that 
>   $$3(\sin x -\cos x)^4 +4(\sin^6 x +\cos^6x) +6(\sin x +\cos x)^2 =13$$

I cannot get it to an expression which does not have any trigonometric function

I have tried this problem several times,

but all I get is
$ 13 + \ldots$

The part after $13$ I find irreducable.

Comment: Can you please add the irreducible part after the 13. That will help us help you find your error.

Answer (score 1):

$$\\ 3\left(\sin \left(x\right)-\cos \right)^{ 4 }+4\left(\sin ^{ 6 }x+\cos ^{ 6 }x\right)+6\left(\sin x+\cos x\right)^{ 2 }=13\\ 3{ \left( { \left( \sin  { x } -\cos  { x }  \right)  }^{ 2 } \right)  }^{ 2 }+4\left( \sin  ^{ 2 }{ x } +\cos  ^{ 2 }{ x }  \right) \left( \sin  ^{ 4 }{ x } -\sin  ^{ 2 }{ x } \cos  ^{ 2 }{ x } +\cos  ^{ 4 }{ x }  \right) +6\left( \sin  ^{ 2 }{ x } +2\sin  { x } \cos  { x } +\cos  ^{ 2 }{ x }  \right) =13\\ \\ 3{ \left( \sin  ^{ 2 }{ x } -2\sin  { x } \cos  { x } +\cos  ^{ 2 }{ x }  \right)  }^{ 2 }+4\left( \sin  ^{ 4 }{ x } -\sin  ^{ 2 }{ x } \cos  ^{ 2 }{ x } +\cos  ^{ 4 }{ x }  \right) +6\left( 1+\sin  { 2x }  \right) =13\\ 3{ \left( 1-\sin  { 2x }  \right)  }^{ 2 }+4\left( { \left( \sin  ^{ 2 }{ x } +\cos  ^{ 2 }{ x }  \right)  }^{ 2 }-3\sin  ^{ 2 }{ x } \cos  ^{ 2 }{ x }  \right) +6\left( 1+\sin  { 2x }  \right) =13\\ 3{ \left( 1-\sin  { 2x }  \right)  }^{ 2 }+4\left( 1-3\sin  ^{ 2 }{ x } \cos  ^{ 2 }{ x }  \right) +6\left( 1+\sin  { 2x }  \right) =13\\ 3{ \left( 1-\sin  { 2x }  \right)  }^{ 2 }+4\left( 1-\frac { 3 }{ 4 } \sin  ^{ 2 }{ 2x }  \right) +6\left( 1+\sin  { 2x }  \right) =13\\ 3-6\sin  { 2x } +3\sin  ^{ 2 }{ 2x } +4-3\sin  ^{ 2 }{ x } +6+6\sin  { 2x } =13$$
So :
$$13=13$$

Answer (score 1):

$\sin^6x+\cos^6x=(\sin^2x)^3+(\cos^2x)^3$
$=(\sin^2x+\cos^2x)^3-3\sin^2x\cos^2x(\sin^2x+\cos^2x)$

$\implies A=\sin^6x+\cos^6x=1-3\sin^2x\cos^2x$

Now,$(\sin x-\cos x)^2=1-2\sin x\cos x$

$\implies B=(\sin x-\cos x)^4=\cdots=(1-2\sin x\cos x)^2$
$=1-4\sin x\cos x+4\sin^2x\cos^2x$

To eliminate $\sin^2x\cos^2x,$

$$4A+3B=7-12\sin x\cos x$$

Now $C=(\sin x+\cos x)^2=1+2\sin x\cos x$

Eliminate $\sin x\cos x$  by $$4A+3B+6C=?$$

Answer (score 0):

$$3(\sin x -\cos x)^4 +4(\sin^6 x +\cos^6x) +6(\sin x +\cos x)^2$$

$$=3(\sin^4x-4\sin^3x\cos x+6\sin^2x\cos^2x-4\sin x\cos^3x+\cos^4x)+4(\sin^6x+\cos^6x)+6(\sin^2x+2\sin x\cos x+\cos^2 x)$$

$$=3\sin^4x-12\sin^3x\cos x+18\sin^2x\cos^2x-12\sin x\cos^3x+3\cos^4x+4\sin^6x+4\cos^6x+6\sin^2x+12\sin x\cos x+6\cos^2 x$$

$$=3\sin^4x-12\sin^3\cos x+18\sin^2x(1-\sin^2x)-12\sin x\cos x(1-\sin^2x)+3(1-\sin^2x)^2+4\sin^6x+4(1-\sin^2x)^3+6\sin^2x+12\sin x\cos x+6(1-\sin^2x)$$

$$=3\sin^4x-12\sin^3\cos x+18\sin^2x-18\sin^4x-12\sin x\cos x+12\sin^3x\cos x+3-6\sin^2x+3\sin^4x+4\sin^6x+4-12\sin^2x+12\sin^4x-4\sin^6x+6\sin^2x+12\sin x\cos x+6-{6\sin^2x}$$

$$=\color{red}{3\sin^4x}\color{blue}{-12\sin^3\cos x}\color{green}{+18\sin^2x}\color{red}{-18\sin^4x}\color{yellow}{-12\sin x\cos x}\color{blue}{+12\sin^3x\cos x}+3\color{green}{-6\sin^2x}\color{red}{+3\sin^4x}\color{cyan}{+4\sin^6x}+4\color{green}{-12\sin^2x}\color{red}{+12\sin^4x}\color{cyan}{-4\sin^6x}\color{green}{+6\sin^2x}\color{yellow}{+12\sin x\cos x}+6\color{green}{-6\sin^2x}$$

$$=13$$